# Func returning false while evaluating

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Any idea why the func is returning false? Equals does not fire as well!!!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        Func<Person, SomethingElse, bool> matchNested = 
            (p, s) => p.Nested == s.Nested;

        var matched = matchNested(new Person()
            {
                Age = 10, 
                Nested = new Nested()
                    {
                        Validity = DateTime.Today
                    }
            },
            new SomethingElse()
            {
                Age = 10, 
                Nested = new Nested()
                    {
                        Validity = DateTime.Today
                    }
            });

        Console.WriteLine(matched);
    }
}

internal class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Nested Nested { get; set; }
}

internal class SomethingElse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Nested Nested { get; set; }
}

internal class Nested
{
    public DateTime Validity { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {     
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.Validity.Equals((obj as Nested).Validity))
            return false;

        return base.Equals(obj);

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: The `throw` is not commented ?

Comment: The way you are using `DateTime.Today` is not good enough for production software.  This is asking for elusive issues just around midnight.  Call this property only once per the whole operation.

Comment: You removed the function from the question... It's hard to answer something about code that you don't show...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I'm not going to bother trying to figure out what your `Equals` code is trying to do, I'm just saying why it isn't being called and why you are always getting false.</sub>

By default the `==` operator returns true for reference types where they point at the *same* object, [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).

So what you could do is [overload the operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your `Nested` class, or call `p.Nested.Equals(s.Nested)`. If you go the overload route, you will need to overload `!=` also.

If you go the `Equals` route, you can have your `Nested` class implement the [`Equatable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) so you get a strongly-typed `Equals` method instead of one taking `object`.

Comment: But I'm not pointing at the same object!!! Each Nested has new Nested() instances.

Comment: @Mike Exactly... so you know you are not point at the same object and the documentation says how `==` will behave. That is why it constantly returns false for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work you need to make sure you also override the == operator on Nested - you have only overridden Equals but you are calling Nested == Nested

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want two Nested types to be equal if their Validity properties are equal.
If so, remove from Equals() the "return base.Equals(obj)" and change the line above it as follows:

return (this.Validity.Equals((obj as Nested).Validity));

Also, Equals() won't be called unless you also change your Func<> like so:

Func matchNested = (p, s) => p.Nested.Equals(s.Nested);